# Phonegap application getting crash when entered in background mode

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm working on application in ios using PhoneGap(1.9).Following are the issue's i'm facing with quiet few hours...

1)My application is getting crash when application enters in background mode.

2)Also,how to disable splash screen.I have deleted default.png image,but still it is showing splash screen with phonegap logo followed by white blank screen.

Thanks & regards.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I'm having the same problem with background mode.

However, regarding splash screen, I can tell you that you have to replace the specific file for the screen size. It generates images for all of the screen sizes and you have to replace them in the built folder, not just the original project folder (at least I seem to have to do this).
The built folder is at the path that should look like /MyProject/platforms/ios/www/res/screen/ios/[screen_specific_splash_screens]

Similarly I had to do the same for the icons:
/MyProject/platforms/ios/www/res/icon/ios/[screen_specific_icons]

Docs for these files (talks about which screen sizes):
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html